# Dynamic amount of observables with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic, knockout.js

I have a basic question related to the knockout.js library.

So far I am creating some input fields of the types number and range.

```
<input type="range" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.001" data-bind="value: example1" ></input>
<input type="number" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.001" data-bind="value: example1"></input>

<input type="range" min="0.5" max="2.5" step="0.001" data-bind="value: example2" ></input>
<input type="number" min="0.5" max="2.5" step="0.001" data-bind="value: example2"></input>
```

When activating knockout.js I am just doing something like

```
this.example1 = ko.observable("0.000");
this.example2 = ko.observable("0.000");
```

---

My problem is that the website receives a random amount of those input parameters. For some projects there are only 2 like in my example while others take like 8 parameters.

How can I specify a dynamic amount of those observables in knockout?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Solved.

In continuation to the selected answer's solution:

With the "attr" binding I was able to set different attribute values for each input.

```
<input type="number" step="0.001" data-bind="value: value, attr: {id: name, min: minValue, max: maxValue}"></input>
```

Comment: Your edit (with solution) is almost unrelated to your question. Your question asked how to have a view-model with a variable number of observables, yet your solution details how you've data-bound HTML attributes.

Comment: My edit was meant to be a continuation of the selected answer's solution. It may help people who face the same problem and stumble upon the question on how to use this solution with data-bound HTML attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an observable array of observables.  Create an observable array and for each of the results returned by the server .push() a new observable or object with observables into the observable array.

Then in the Dom use the for each binding to iterate over them and show each one.

In the VM -

```
var objectsArray = ko.observableArray();

// results from AJAX or w/e
ko.utils.arrayForEach(results, function (result) {
    objectsArray.push(new ObjectType(result));
});

function ObjectType (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.SomeProperty = ko.observable(data);
}
```

Then in the view

```
<div data-bind="foreach: objectsArray">
    <input data-bind="value: SomeProperty " />
</div>
```

jsFiddle example -

http://jsfiddle.net/zabpe3jm/

Comment: Er... haven't you just edited your answer so that it looks a heckuvalot like mine?

Comment: rofl - I answered on my phone way before you did and had to come back and add code examples on my pc.  Trust me I didn't look at your answer, thx tho

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine and I just had to find out about the "attr" binding to get different attribute values for each input.

Comment: Isn't there an error in this answer? The view-model has an observable called `SomeProperty` yet the HTML example calls an observable called `$data`.

Comment: @awj Fiddle works, if you feel there is an error feel free to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, JavaScript makes it quite easy to add properties to an object as and when needed, so it wouldn't be difficult to have a view-model which accurately reflected your data.

On the other hand, the tricky part would be having HTML with `data-bind` attributes which would accurately reflect your dynamic view-model.

One possible solution would be to refactor your view-model into two:

```
function viewModelContainer(arrData) {

    var self = this;

    // this holds a dynamic number of elements, depending upon the data from the server
    self.Observables = ko.observableArray([]);

    // using an IIFE as a type of constructor for getting the 
    // `arrData` param into your observable
    (function(arrData) {
        // add all elements in a single call so that you don't cause
        // multiple unnecessary updates to the UI
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0, iMax == arrData.length; i < iMax; i++) {
            arr.push(new viewModelData(arrData[i]));
        }
        self.Observables.push(arr);
    }(arrData));
}


function viewModelData(data) {

    var self = this;

    self.Data = ko.observable(data);
}
```

So now you have a single object/view-model (an instance of `viewModelContainer`) which *knows* how many values it contains.

The next step would be to enumerate these (using [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)) in your HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Observables -->
    <input type="range" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.001" data-bind="value: Data" ></input>
    <input type="number" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.001" data-bind="value: Data"></input>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I've written that *free-hand* / from memory, so you might need to polish it, but I hope you get the gist.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want to use `observable`, but use `observableArray` instead

```
this.yourObjects = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Then, assuming you have some source array that will contain the input parameters, you would just add them to the array:

```
for (var i in sourceArray) {
    this.yourObjects.push(sourceArray[i]);
}
```

To render it, simply use a foreach binding:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: yourObjects">
    <input type="range" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.001" data-bind="value: $data" ></input>
</div>
```

Notice that you use "value: $data" because you don't want some property of the item, but the item itself (like your number value)